# I was told to bring a dessert that is NOT savory....what would you infer is meant?

Tags: flavor, dessert

I realize that savory and sweet are not opposites, but being asked to bring dessert as long as it is NOT savory leads me to think there should be some component of sweetness, absent of added salts or spices. Am I correct, perhaps fruit flavored for example such as a tart or buttery with a touch of sweet? Was my host eluding to something that's not bland yet not sugary sweet?

Comment: I would take it as the whole range from neutral to sweet.  You can name a dessert and ask if it is OK.

Comment: How exactly was this phrased? Is it possible it was "a dessert - not something savory" and it was just repetition/clarification, not describing a subcategory of desserts?

Comment: ...don't bring a cheese course.

Comment: salt or spices don't make everything savory either ... things like sticky rice+mango or mincemeat pies are certainly on the sweet side of things, though they do contain a savory element...

Answer (score 1):

Because so many cakes, sweet tarts, and classical sweet desserts can be made with a sprinkle of salt (and this is in the recipes of a lot of sweets) I don't think we are looking at a dessert with no spices nor salt.

It might be tasteless.

I'm guessing, without knowing the context, that it meant no onion tart, mushroom bell pepper tart, or prosciutto wrapped fruits etc.

When sugar was first abundantly available in Europe, a lot of cooks put sugar on everything - meat, stews and so on. There might be something in our food history where desserts, sweet and savory, combined a lot more than today.

Comment: Along with no vegetable tarts, maybe... no Parmesan or savory sesame seed ice cream, no garlic and shallot brittle, or candied bacon, or doritos cupcakes, tomato and herb cheesecake, and perhaps not even a cheese plate.